# Change the default green color of JFXDatePicker

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-datepicker

The default color for JFXDatePicker seems to be green. How do I change it to a different color, lets say red?

[image]

I tried the following but they seem to change colors of different elements

1. `-fx-background-color` : This only changed the input background color
   [image]
2. `-fx-control-inner-background` : This changed the white background to red but does not change the currently green part.
   [image]

Could you please help me out what style do we need to apply to change the green color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will change the month-year-pane to red color:

```
.date-picker-popup > .month-year-pane {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! Where do I need to look for names of these different elements?

Comment: @DinesG if you mean to find css class names you can use this free open source tool for javafx apps: github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view